# Rails filter JSON Object on render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, filter

I have a JSON string and I use:

```
objJson = JSON.parse(jsonString)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :json => objJson.to_json(:include =>  [:ID, :Name]) }
end
```

The problem is that `to_json` only works on models, so it just ignores my filters.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
 "count":29,
 "results":
 [
   {"ID":556036109,"Name":"Mojos", "Url":"https://mojos/id300751949","currency":"USD"},
   {"ID":556036110,"Name":"Asav", "Url":"https://asav/id300751949","currency":"USD"}
 ]
}
```

Is there any way to filter the JSON object on render?

---

### UPDATE:

I used *ssorallen* code:

```
KEYS_TO_KEEP = ['ID', 'Name']
objJson = JSON.parse(jsonString)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render :json => objJson['results'].keep_if {|k, v| KEYS_TO_KEEP.include?(k)}}
end
```

The problem is that objJson['results'] returned an Array to Hashes and not a single Hash.

So the right way to do it was:

```
objJson = objJson['results'].each { |x| x.keep_if {|k, v| KEYS_TO_KEEP.include?(k)} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the methods on Ruby hashes like [`keep_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if):

```
KEYS_TO_KEEP = ['ID', 'Name']
objJson['results'] =
  objJson['results'].keep_if {|k, v| KEYS_TO_KEEP.include?(k)}

format.html {render :json => objJson}
```

Comment: Hey, i added my JSON to the question. Your solution work if i use:
`@KEYS_TO_KEEP = ["results"]` but i cant choose specific keys from the results array. Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by, "i cant choose specific keys from the results array"? Can you post example code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the delay i didn't notice you edited the question.. Anyway still not working, i tried objJson['results'].include?('ID') on console just for test and it returned false.. though `objJson['results']` returns a json array.